# No Apps can perform this action android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to make this program that when the user clicks a button, a message is sent to a whatsapp number

Here is the code in the onClick method

```
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "xxxxxxxxxx"); //xxx.. is the mobile number
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check");
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

It shows that there are no apps that can perform this action. Why?

I removed

```
            i.setType("text/plain");
```

And it works. But the text "Check" is not sent. How to do that if this is not the way.

Comment: what is your logcat ?

Comment: whatsapp dont provide a public api . you have very little functionality to do with it. take a look at this post https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

Answer (score 0):

Your format is slightly different from the example given on the WhatsApp FAQ, so I would modify to match.

From [this page](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012):

> Like most social apps on Android, WhatsApp listens to intents to share media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example, and WhatsApp will be displayed by the system picker:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

> However, if you prefer to share directly to WhatsApp and bypass the system picker, you can do so by using setPackage in your intent:

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

> This would simply be set right before you call startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: Hey, what i need is that the message is sent and not just the user directed to the "pick a contact" screen

Comment: That is probably against their terms of service. You could be sending anything. My guess is thats by design

Comment: No. There are many apps which use this service. Such as apps which can reply to whatsapp messages on the home screen itself etc

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code to send ON whatsapp**

```
public void SendWhatsapp(View view) {

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
try {

    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
    //in catch block will be called
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
  }  

 }
```